# Twilio Can't Reply Message With MessagingResponse

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have Twilio's paid account. I had set up a webhook for an active number. Currently, I am using `MessagingResponse` to reply messages with any number and send a message to a number had a webhook. But I got an error with status  `30008 Unknown error`. What is solution for this error?

This is the code handle hook and send reply message:

```
 public async hookTwilioSMS(payload: ITwilioWebhookPayload): Promise<MessagingResponse> {
    const messagingResponse: MessagingResponse = new Twiml.MessagingResponse()
    const incomingMessage: string = payload?.Body ?? ''

    messagingResponse.message(
      {
        to: payload.From
      },
      'help'
    )

    return messagingResponse 
  }
```

This is the error log:
[error log image part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcimB.png)
[error log image part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBRRr.png)

Comment: Async await????  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2487730

Comment: thank you for your comment. I fixed but this error is still there, I think the main point of this error log on twilio console

Comment: Are we talking the same Twilio Markup Language?  Your code doesn't look anything like what I see at https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml#a-basic-twiml-sms-response-example